# Dividing circumference into equal parts and returning coordinates

Tags: python, geometry

I have created several circles with different origins using Python and I am trying to implement a function that will divide each circle into `n` number of equal parts along the circumference.  I am trying to populate an array that contains the starting `[x,y]` coordinate for each part on the circumference.

My code is as follows:

```
def fnCalculateArcCoordinates(self,intButtonCount,radius,center):
        lstButtonCoord = []

        #for degrees in range(0,360,intAngle):
        for arc in range(1,intButtonCount + 1):
            degrees = arc * 360 / intButtonCount
            xDegreesCoord = int(center[0] + radius * math.cos(math.radians(degrees)))
            yDegreesCoord = int(center[1] + radius * math.sin(math.radians(degrees)))

            lstButtonCoord.append([xDegreesCoord,yDegreesCoord])
        
        return lstButtonCoord
```

When I run the code for 3 parts, an example of the set of coordinates that are returned are:

```
[[157, 214], [157, 85], [270, 149]]
```

This means the segments are of different sizes.  Could someone please help me identify where my error is?

Comment: What is the motivation of switching to degrees only to switch back to radians? Surely you can divide `2*math.pi` into equal parts and skip the conversions. Note that whatever you do, a certain amount of round-off error is inevitable (especially with the final conversion to int). The 3 points you have actually seem reasonable enough.If you plot them they look like an equilateral triangle.  What 3 points would be better?

Comment: If you really want to get as close as possible with integer coordinates, it becomes a non-trivial non-linear integer programming problem. As a heuristic, you could start with your current solution and then look into tweaking it by perturbing each point by a pixel. Use `itertoools` to loop through all possible combinations of 1-pixel perturbations and see if any give you less overall error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact results of such trigonometric calculations are rarely exact integers. By flooring them to `int`, you lose some precision, of course. The approximate (Pythagorean) distance checks suggest that your math is correct:

```
(270-157)**2 + (149-85)**2
# 16865
(270-157)**2 + (214-149)**2
# 16994
(157-157)**2 + (214-85)**2
# 16641
```

Furthermore, you can use the built-in `complex` number type and the `cmath` module. In particular [`cmath.rect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html#cmath.rect) converts polar coordinates (a radius and an angle) into rectangular coordinates:

```
import cmath

def calc(count, radius, center):
    x, y = center
    for i in range(count):
        r = cmath.rect(radius, (2*cmath.pi)*(i/count))
        yield [round(x+r.real, 2), round(y+r.imag, 2)]

list(calc(4, 2, [0, 0]))
# [[2.0, 0.0], [0.0, 2.0], [-2.0, 0.0], [-0.0, -2.0]]
list(calc(6, 1, [0, 0]))
# [[1.0, 0.0], [0.5, 0.87], [-0.5, 0.87], [-1.0, 0.0], [-0.5, -0.87], [0.5, -0.87]]
```

You want to change rounding as you see fit.

Comment: While this is more elegant than OP's code (+1) it is unlikely to avoid the issue which they seem to be worried about (the lack of exactness when approximating to points on the integer lattice).

Comment: @JohnColeman True. Added some explanation to that end.